# Realizar un ciclo donde ingresen números, luego se sume sus digitos repitiendo esto hasta que ingrese -1 y al final muestre cuantos digitos son pares

Tags: python-3.x

Al ejecutar no me dice cuantos dígitos son pares, al poner el -1 me dice que son 0 pares

```
x=0
n=int(input("Número: "))
while n!=-1:
    if n%2 == 0:
        x+=1
    y=0
    while n!=0:
        z=n%10
        y+=z
        n=n//10
    print("Suma de los dígitos:", y)
    n=int(input("Número: "))
print("Se ingresaron", x, "números pares")
```

Comment: Espera. Entonces el enunciado del ejercicio pide que despues de ingresar -1 el programa diga cuantos **digitos** son pares? O sea si ingreso 210 y 322 debería devolver 3?

Comment: @DanteS. Exactamente

Answer (score 1):

Una solución "pythonesca"

```
numero = input("Ingrese número: ")

while numero != "-1":
    digitos = [int(x) for x in numero]
    pares = [x for x in digitos if x % 2 == 0]
    suma = sum(digitos)
    n_pares = len(pares)
    print("Suma de digitos: ", suma)
    print("Digitos pares: ", pares)
    print("Número de digitos pares: ", n_pares)

    numero = input("Ingrese número: ")
```

El número lo ingresamos como string; no hay necesidad de convertirlo a entero.

Para Python una cadena es igual que una lista, por lo que

```
    digitos = [int(x) for x in numero]
```

recorre el número dígito por dígito, convirtiendolo a entero y guardandolo en la lista `digitos`.

Los dígitos pares se obtiene mediante comprensión de listas, recorriendo la lista `digitos`, seleccionando aquellos que sean pares:

```
    pares = [x for x in digitos if x % 2 == 0]
```

Para sumar los digitos, usamos `sum()`, y la cantidad de pares la obtenemos con `len()`.

#### Demo

```
Ingrese número: 314159
Suma de digitos:  23
Digitos pares:  {4}
Número de digitos pares:  1
Ingrese número: -1

Process finished with exit code 0
```